# SwiftMailer not sending message

Tags: php, swiftmailer

I'm learning about swift and when a run my code, throws the exception:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Swift_SmtpTransport::send()

<?php

    include_once "swift_required.php";

    $subject = 'Hello from Mandrill, PHP!';
    $from = array('you@yourdomain.com' =>'Your Name');
    $to = array(
     'recipient1@example.com'  => 'Recipient1 Name',
     'recipient2@example2.com' => 'Recipient2 Name'
    );

    $text = "Mandrill speaks plaintext";
    $html = "<em>Mandrill speaks <strong>HTML</strong></em>";

    $transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.mandrillapp.com', 587);
    $transport->setUsername('MANDRILL_USERNAME');
    $transport->setPassword('MANDRILL_PASSWORD');

    $message = new Swift_Message($subject);
    $message->setFrom($from);
    $message->setBody($html, 'text/html');
    $message->setTo($to);
    $message->addPart($text, 'text/plain');

    if ($recipients = $transport->send($message, $failures))
    {
     echo 'Message successfully sent!';
    } else {
     echo "There was an error:\n";
     print_r($failures);
    }
```

http://pastebin.com/vBNSxgWq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing:

```
$swift = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
```

And instead of

```
transport->send
```

it should be:

```
$swift->send
```

Answer (score 3):

Method `send` is available in Swift_Mailer class, not in Transport. It's easy to create an instance of mailer:

```
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
```